# Cannot start SQL Server service

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having problems starting the SQL Server (`SQLEXPRESS`) service.

When I press "Start" it says

> Windows could not start the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)...

and refers to service-specific error code 17113

Event viewer:

> Error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while opening file 'D:\Programi\SQL\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf' to obtain configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or remove them if necessary.

So as I believe I am missing `master.mdf`. But where do I get one? I might have deleted it somehow.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: `master.mdf` is part of the installation - do ***NOT*** delete any of the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files that the installation creates! If you don't have that file anymore --> time to re-install SQL Server Express

Comment: Easiest way to fix this is probably to reinstall.

Comment: Yeah I am reinstalling at it at the moment. I don't know why on earth did I delete master.mdf (a big missclick maybe).

Comment: `D:\Programi` looks suspicious. Is it possible someone was messing around in the SSMS UI and somehow changed a path? Or is there really a `Programi` folder on your D drive?

Comment: Yeah there is folder named Programi.